# Last shot at undestanding what context is in Android

Tags: android

This will be my last try to understand what context means in Android, otherwise I will leave Android development because I don't understand why nobody can give a good answer to this. I do NOT WANT a copy paste from the Android docs that tell me that it is a interface for accessing resources. Either will I accept links to other questions because I have read them all, otherwise I wouldn't have asked.

As the documentation states it is a interface to the resources.

**1st question**
What is context? What does it mean that it is a interface to the resources?

**2nd question**
Why do we then pass this around all the time, would not every activity etc. have access to the same resources?

**3rd question**
Why is context needed in every friggin scenario? Such as `Button myButton = new Button(this);`

**4th question**
Yet another question about why context is passed to e.g. listadapters?

Thank you for your time:)

Comment: I don't care actually. In order for me to understand it I don't need yet another link to the documentation, and then I can enlighten people with that before they answer. And who are you to judge? ah....thats right you are yet another badge/point hunter at SO hahaha. Have a nice day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it help you to visualise a `Context` as a pointer to your parent object?

So, this is why in your example you create a `Button` with

```
Button myButton = new Button ( this );
```

The button (and Android) needs to know with which `Activity` it is to be associated in order to properly manage resources (as you yourself has said - don't forget, it's for Android just as much as for you or your user) and to know for example, when to trigger your `onClick()`. Without knowing in which `Context` your button exists, how does Android know whether to show it or not? How does Android know whether to send onClick() events or not? It's because it knows the context of the button.

If your buttons context is the same as the active Activity, then it's visible to the user and needs to be managed differently to an object that is not visible - for instance, the visible Activity and it's resources will be the last objects to be killed in an out-of-memory situation.

This is no different really to other operating systems and graphical toolkits, it's just different terminology.

A Context *is* an interface to resources, but the touchscreen is a resource, memory is a resource, the CPU is a resource - you are thinking too narrowly about what constitutes a resource (and again, it's really just semantics); resources aren't just sound files, or icons, or layouts - there are resources that Android manages too, and it needs to know the `Context` of your objects in order to manage those external resources properly.

Comment: Thank YOU!! A last one guy that gives answer that make me understand what context is, and who is not a douche that many on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No problem - sometimes it's easy to get caught up in the terminology and miss the concept completely. I myself have tried to explain Contexts before, unsuccessfully before I came up with this explanation today. I guess I've always just implicitly made the connection or accepted it. It doesn't help that in all the samples, the `Context` variable is called `context` or `ctxt` instead of `parent`

Answer (score 1):

Context is a means to register your objects with the system so that whenever system wants to respond to your object, it could be identified uniquely.
If you do not register your button with the system then the listener will not get the correct event and hence it will create mess and make your system crash/slow.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of context is deep rooted in android. In simple terms here is my explanation:

1. Android is a multi-threaded platform.
2. There in one UI thread where everything the user sees is drawn and in the background there can be 'n' worker threads.
3. Every activity/service runs on its own thread.
4. Every activity has a local set of layouts/images/mp3's etc.
5. Every activity is identified in runtime by its 'Context'. Think of it as an identifier. Thus anything you might want to do within that activity you should do it with a reference of the context.

Hope this is a favorable answer for questions 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

> 1st question What is context? What
>   does it mean that it is a interface to
>   the  resources?

Hmm.. Context I believe you understand that it tells you where exactly you are. As you know the concept of this pointer in Java it is same as that. The system provides each application a context. The resources needs to be mentioned that it has to be used in this context. And all these because Android is multi-threaded. It is not that you enter inside an activity and you will be dealing with just one thread.

> 2nd question Why do we then pass this
>   around all the time, would not every
>   activity etc. have access to the same
>   resources?

Well when we have one class and an inner class then if you use "this" inside the inner class then your components will take the inner class context and not the outer class context even if you meant the outer class. Here you will have to specify by saying your outer class name.this i.e you are specifying clearly that you want to use the outer class context.

> Why is context needed in every friggin
>   scenario?  Such as `Button myButton = new
>   Button(this)`;

Now Button and any other widget needs to be known on which view they need to be. So by telling the context you make it clear to the widget. Say I have two classes inside a java file and now you use a button widget. How will the widget know exactly where it has to go.

I hope the answer for your forth question is also the same.